# Toastbar in desktop build

Tags: codenameone

Today I deployed a windows desktop build. It’s quite ok, but an odd fact is that Toastbars are not shown. I understand that a Toastbar is more suitable on a mobile ui than a desktop ui, however why isn’t shown?

Comment: Is it possibly due to the dark mode?
Notice that the simulator supports desktop windows mode, are the toastbar notifications shown there?

Comment: This morning the Toastbars are displayed, I don't know exactly what to think: maybe I was wrong, or maybe last night dark mode was on and this morning it wasn't (but does dark mode exist also on Windows?). Anyway, I had a lot of problems in the styling of the app: I wanted to have the same styling as iOS, but I couldn't do it. In the end I solved it with `includeNativeBool: false;` and re-created from scratch all the relevant styles.

Comment: I'm unaware of any change that went in that should impact that but maybe something in yesterdays update fixed a problem